# How to create a system that turns an input into a combination of numbers in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a system that takes a key from the user. e.g. 'ab'. Convert the letters into their position on the alphabet, (ab = 1, 2) and then add them together. So an example would look like.

Input: abc

Output: 6

This is what I've tried so far.

```
String alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
        System.out.println("Please input a key");
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        String keyInput = key.nextLine();



        for (int i = 0; i < keyInput.length(); i++) {
            char letter = keyInput.charAt(i);
            int[] alphLetter = new int[alphabet.indexOf(letter)];
            System.out.println(alphLetter[i]);
```

Comment: Why do you create the array ``alphLetter``? I don't feel its needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if `alphabet` will always be in the standard order or if it could be shuffled?

If you're just dealing with the standard alphabet you can do something simple like this:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<keyInput.length(); i++)
{
    sum += 1 + keyInput.charAt(i) - 'a';
}
System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
```

If the `alphabet` could be shuffled you'll first need to build a map of character positions. You can use a simple array for this.

```
String alphabet = "mgpqrhivwxjklostufncbyzade";
int[] charPos = new int[alphabet.length()];
for(int i=0; i<alphabet.length(); i++) 
    charPos[alphabet.charAt(i)-'a'] =  i + 1;

int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<keyInput.length(); i++)
{
    sum += charPos[keyInput.charAt(i)-'a'];
}
System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a character's position in the alphabet by subtracting `'a'` from it (and adding one, since you want it one-based). I think the easier approach would be to stream the characters of the string, convert them to their positions and sum them:

```java
int result = key.chars().map(c -> c - 'a' + 1).sum();
```

Comment: `filter(c -> c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')`

Comment: I'm unsure how I would implement that into my code.